# How can update trained IsolationForest model with new datasets/datafarmes in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, isolation-forest, online-machine-learning

Let's say I fit [`IsolationForest()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html#sklearn-ensemble-isolationforest) algorithm from scikit-learn on time-series based Dataset1 or dataframe1 `df1` and save the model using the methods mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47156906/how-to-save-an-isolationforest-model-in-python) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69227131/how-to-save-pickle-isolationforest-model-in-python). Now I want to update my model for **new** dataset2 or `df2`.

My findings:

- this [workaround](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/68599/incremental-learning-with-sklearn-warm-start-partial-fit-fit) about [Incremental learning](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning) from sklearn:

> ...learn incrementally from a mini-batch of instances (sometimes called “online learning”) is key to out-of-core learning as it guarantees that at any given time, there will be only a small amount of instances in the main memory. Choosing a good size for the mini-batch that balances relevancy and memory footprint could involve tuning.

but Sadly IF algorithm doesn't support `estimator.partial_fit(newdf)`

- auto-sklearn offers [`refit()`](https://automl.github.io/auto-sklearn/master/api.html#autosklearn.regression.AutoSklearnRegressor.refit) is also not suitable for my case based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52586577/using-refit-in-auto-sklearn-for-incremental-learning).

How I can update the trained on Dataset1 and saved IF model  with a new Dataset2?

Comment: When you say _`update`_, do you mean retrain it on new observations, or make predictions?

Comment: by *update the trained/saved IF model* I mean **re-train** on new observation not predict.

Comment: short note Imagine I'm using IF algorithms for anomaly detection on time-series based stream data. so after a while, I need to update/re-train my saved/trained  IF model. I can't use the IF trained/saved IF model which fit for 2019, for new observations for 2022 due to different possible distribution behaviour on data from different times [years or months].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply reuse the `.fit()` call [available to the estimator](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html#sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.fit) on the new data.

This would be preferred, especially in a time series, as the signal changes and you do not want older, non-representative data to be understood as potentially normal (or anomalous).

If old data is important, you can simply join the older training data and newer input signal data together, and then call `.fit()` again.

Also sidenote, [according to sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html), it is better to use [`joblib`](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) than `pickle`

An [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with resources below:

```
# Model
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest

# Saving file
import joblib

# Data
import numpy as np

# Create a new model
model = IsolationForest()

# Generate some old data
df1 = np.random.randint(1,100,(100,10))
# Train the model
model.fit(df1)

# Save it off
joblib.dump(model, 'isf_model.joblib')

# Load the model
model = joblib.load('isf_model.joblib')

# Generate new data
df2 = np.random.randint(1,500,(1000,10))

# If the original data is now not important, I can just call .fit() again.
# If you are using time-series based data, this is preferred, as older data may not be representative of the current state
model.fit(df2)

# If the original data is important, I can simply join the old data to new data. There are multiple options for this:
# Pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html
# Numpy: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html

combined_data = np.concatenate((df1, df2))
model.fit(combined_data)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Despite concatenation of dfs and reuse `fit()` sounds very straightforward, does it make sense to do this on the scale of big/stream data (imagine I have 10M records every day that need lots of memory)? It's not possible to update the weights you trained in previous training phases?

Comment: You _can_, though there are probably more efficient ways. Not using `scikit-learn`, or other well-known libraries like `pyod`. Online type learning for time-series like analyses are not traditionally used in algorithms like isolation forests (though they certainly can!). For datasets that big, you might consider storing your data in `Vaex` dataframes.